# How to plot ggplot using for loop?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there any efficient way to plot ggplot using for loop? How to regular express the coloname that will be put in the ggplot function?

for example how should I regular express『satisfaction』 and『Flight.Distance』in the code?

```
ggplot(data = t1, aes(x = Flight.Distance))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density.., color =satisfaction, fill =satisfaction),  alpha = 0.4, position = "identity") +
  geom_density(aes(color = satisfaction), size =1)
```

[image]
I had succeeded once using the following code:

```
plot_data_column_2 = function (data, column1, column2) {
  ggplot(data, aes_string(x = column1, fill = column2)) +
    geom_bar(position = position_dodge())+
    guides(fill=guide_legend(title=sprintf('%s', column2)))+
    xlab(sprintf('%s', column2))
}

plot_data_column_2(data = data1, column1 = 'clus_res', column2 = 'Gender')
```

[image]

Yet, I can't replicate this experience on geom_histogram. I had tried some stupid methods but getting terrible output

```
ggplot(data = t1, aes(x = Flight.Distance))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density.., color =t1[['satisfaction']] ,fill =t1[['satisfaction']]),  alpha = 0.4, position = "identity") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title='satisfaction'))+
  geom_density(aes(color = t1[['satisfaction']]), size =1)
```

[image]

So I try to solve this problem by removing the legend guide and add it back later on. But the legend is gone for good

```
ggplot(data = t1, aes(x = t1[['Flight.Distance']]))+
  xlab('Flight.Distance')+
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density.., color =t1[['satisfaction']] ,fill =t1[['satisfaction']]),  alpha = 0.4, position = "identity") +
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  guides(col = guide_legend(ncol = 23))+
  geom_density(aes(color = t1[['satisfaction']]), size =1)
```

[image]

Comment: As an aside, it may be better to stratify the distances for a clearer visual representation by total flight time or distance.  That would lead to fewer bars without a reduction in message clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using aes_string is possible, it is ["soft deprecated"](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html#life-cycle) and a more ideomatic tidyverse approach is to use the ["curly curly" {{ }} operator from tidyeval](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/#a-simpler-interpolation-pattern-with-):

```
my_plot <- function(df, x_var, group_var) {
  df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = {{x_var}},
               color = {{group_var}},
               fill  = {{group_var}},
               group = {{group_var}})) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..),
                   alpha = 0.4, position = "identity") +
    geom_density(size = 1, fill = NA)
}

my_plot(mtcars, mpg, factor(am))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved !
Sorry, I found that I forgot to add an important function which is  'aes_string', after adding it my code worked again.

```
ggplot(data = t1, aes_string(x = 'Flight.Distance'))+
  geom_histogram(aes_string(y = '..density..', color ='satisfaction', fill ='satisfaction'),  alpha = 0.4, position = "identity") +
  geom_density(aes_string(color = 'satisfaction'), size =1)
```

[image]